# How to customise a tumblr feed on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, feed, tumblr

Hi People and thanks for reading.

I am building a small (one-page) site for my friends band, and am using a tumblr feed instead of news section. The only thing is, I'm a total novice at JS / JQuery.

I've managed to get the posts showing fine, but at the moment the feed pulls the post title, some blurb, and the date (in that order). Because I want to display the date before the title, I'm crudely using some CSS to move the date above the title (position: relative).

So far I have this in the header:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

And this in the body just before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("feeds", "1"); 

      function OnLoad() {       
    var feedControl = new google.feeds.FeedControl();             
    feedControl.setNumEntries(3); 

    feedControl.addFeed("http://xxxxxxxxxx.tumblr.com/rss");             
    feedControl.draw(document.getElementById("recentPosts"));     
}           

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad); 

</script>
```

Does anyone know how I can customise the output so that the date comes before the title?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to hack the html rendered by Google' script; you could try to use jquery in order to make things easier. Just remember to apply your changes after the

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. The only problem is I have no idea how to do it! Could you maybe elaborate slighty?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this (not tested):

```
 <script language="Javascript">
google.load("feeds", "1"); 
function loadFeeds()
{
    var feedControl = new google.feeds.FeedControl();             
    feedControl.setNumEntries(3); 

    var html;
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml");

    feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
        var container = document.getElementById("feed");
        for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

            html+=entry.date+"<p>"+entry.title+"</p>"+entry.description+"<br>";

            document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML =html;
        }
    }
    });   
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(loadFeeds);    
</script>
```